# Package classifier4J

Tags: java, cpu-word, classification

```
import net.sf.classifier4J.Utilities;
import net.sf.classifier4J.summariser.ISummariser;
import net.sf.classifier4J.summariser.SimpleSummariser;
```

I am doing summarizing so i need these packages can anyone tell me from where i can find these packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr. Google tells me that the source repository can be found here: http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/subprojects/core/cvs-usage.html